# Is there any official Docker images for Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, docker

Does anyone where's the official docker images for Hadoop, e.g. YARN, HDFS? I'd like to use them within a docker image.

Comment: Did you try searching [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=Hadoop&starCount=1)?

Comment: @ldg , confirmed with user@hadoop; there's no community version of docker image. And the vendor's docker image did not meet my requirement.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: There's no community version docker of Hadoop, this requirement is traced at [HADOOP-13397](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13397) .

Answer (score 10):

There is not currently an official Hadoop Docker image, but there are many User contributed images on the Docker Hub, including [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/harisekhon/hadoop/) one with over 100K Pulls.

Answer (score 10):

Cloudera now provide their Quickstart VM as a Docker image for single-node deployments:

- [cloudera/quickstart on Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/)
- [Docker is the New QuickStart Option for Apache Hadoop and Cloudera](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/12/docker-is-the-new-quickstart-option-for-apache-hadoop-and-cloudera/) (blog post)

Answer (score 6):

**It's important to check if the chosen image includes only Hadoop.**
 (I'm not sure about Cloudera image mentioned above).

**Check out the alternatives below:**

1. **Sequenceiq**: 
   [Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker) (+1M pulls)
   [Github repo](https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker).
   [Site](http://sequenceiq.com/)
   Pull with:
   `docker pull sequenceiq/hadoop-docker`
2. **Uhopper**:
   [Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/uhopper/hadoop/)(1M+ pulls)
   [Bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/uhopper/hadoop-docker/src/master/)
   [Site](https://www.u-hopper.com/)
   Pull with:
   `docker pull uhopper/hadoop`
3. **Big data europe**:
   [Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bde2020/hadoop-base/) (10K+ pulls)
   [Github repo](https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop)
   [Site](https://www.big-data-europe.eu/)
   Pull with:
   `docker pull bde2020/hadoop-base`
4. **Parrot Stream**:
   [Image](https://hub.docker.com/r/parrotstream/hadoop/) (1.2K+ pulls)
   [Github repo](https://github.com/parrot-stream/docker-hadoop)
   [Site](https://parrot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#)
   Pull with:
   `docker pull parrotstream/hadoop`

---

Bonus:
Check out [this](http://bigdatums.net/2017/11/04/creating-hadoop-docker-image/) tutorial on how to build Hadoop docker image.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is an official one now: https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/hadoop

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is an official image, but you can take a look at https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop.

[This](https://clubhouse.io/developer-how-to/how-to-set-up-a-hadoop-cluster-in-docker/) blog post teaches how to use it !

Comment: I have managed to start Hadoop locally on Windows 10 using this image and the instructions at: https://www.section.io/engineering-education/set-up-containerize-and-test-a-single-hadoop-cluster-using-docker-and-docker-compose/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the Apache Foundation has added an image for hadoop to docker-hub.
https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/hadoop