# Which docker container should I use to Hadoop?

Tags: docker, hadoop

I'm trying to find a recent version of Hadoop available on docker.
Is there an official Hadoop repository created since 2016 ([Is there any official Docker images for Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447786/is-there-any-official-docker-images-for-hadoop))?

I found some repositories like :

- https://hub.docker.com/r/harisekhon/hadoop/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/uhopper/hadoop/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/mcapitanio/hadoop/

But I don't know if they are good and updated.

Can you help me to find the best image please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cloudera images include much much more than only Hadoop. Therefore I wouldn't suggest that as Docker images should do one thing

I've had success with the SequenceIQ and uhopper images, and the last one in your list is deprecated if you see the description, but in truth, they all will probably work for your purposes unless you really specifically need a Hadoop 3 feature

The ones I've used recently are by bde2020

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I will check if bde2020 image fits my needs.

Comment: Hadoop 2.7 is still the most widely used in Production, AFAIK. So, there's not much reason to use anything different, and all those popular Hadoop images haven't upgraded, I guess

Comment: Ok. So I think I will use https://hub.docker.com/r/uhopper/hadoop/ or https://hub.docker.com/r/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/ which seems to be most popular Hadoop images.